# Phone number of a text message

Tags: 8.0

For a text message, windows phone displays the sender's name if the number is already in my address book.

I have multiple phone numbers for this person in my address book. When this person sends me a text message, how do I find out from which phone number did she send me the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tap the switch button at the bottom (two horizontal arrows), if there are multiple numbers the one you have just interacted with will be highlighted. If you want to switch the number or chat that you are using, you can do that here and all of your communications with that person will continue with the same history.